# android application has stopped while testing on mobile phone

Tags: java, android, google-api

I have finished my app in eclipse, and it works fine in emulator - no errors.
When i try it on mobile phone, it opens normal, two spinners populate from database normal, but when i click on one of menu buttons that has some googgle map operation in background I get this message:

```
"Unfortunately, XXXX has stopped."
```

What can I do now? Is there some program to debug it or log it on mobile phone?
I was building my app for android version 2.3.3(Google api's API lvl 10) and I am testing it on android 4.0, could this be a problem?

**EDIT:**
LogCat shows no errors with android 2.3.3, I don't know how to start it on android 4.0 emulator - it seems it avoids running on 4.0 config emulator - when i click run, it always open a new avd 4.0 emulator machine and nothing else. App doesn't start nor LogCat shows any errors.

**EDIT2:**
I tested it on android 2.3.3 mobile device and it works perfect. I assume problem is in different Google maps APIs( version 2 and new version 3). How can I make my app compatible with old and new Google map api? Any suggestions, links, tutorials?

Comment: ADB LogCat output exists on every mobile phone, just turn USB debugging on - run your app from eclipse and copy the red portion of the stack trace. Then analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse you can view the LogCat log by going to Window>>Show View>>Other>>and select LogCat under Android.  The Log will show the crash and corresponding error codes.

LogCat info can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.